# Full Text Search Not Working Codeigniter with Mssql server

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter

**Full Text Search not working please help me.**

A Database Error Occurred

> Error Number: 42000
>
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Full-Text Search
> is not installed, or a full-text component cannot be loaded.

```
    SELECT judg.id
    ,judg.jud_no
    ,judg.jud_year
    ,judg.book_reference
    ,judg.jurisdiction
    ,judg.case_no
    ,judg.case_source
    ,judg.parties
    ,judg.lawyer
    ,judg.judgment_date
    ,judg.j_date
    ,judg.judgment_date_type
    ,judg.short_description
    ,judg.section
    ,judg.act
    ,judg.article
    ,judg.order_rule
    ,judg.full_judgment
    ,judg.judgment_type
    ,judg.court_division_id
    ,judg.file_name
    ,judg.file_rename
    ,judg.judgment_entry_date
    ,judg.STATUS
    ,judg.user_id
    ,judg.is_pdf
    ,judg.is_table
    ,judg.is_correction
    ,ct.name AS ct_name
    ,cd.name AS cd_name
FROM tbl_jud_judgment judg
LEFT JOIN tbl_jud_case_type_no_year ctny ON ctny.judgment_id = judg.id
LEFT JOIN tbl_jud_case_type ct ON ct.id = ctny.case_type_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_jud_court_division cd ON cd.id = judg.court_division_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_jud_justice_judgment cjud ON cjud.judgment_id = judg.id
LEFT JOIN tbl_jud_justice cjus ON cjus.id = cjud.justice_id
WHERE 1 = 1
    AND (
        judg.case_no LIKE '%dhaka%'
        OR judg.parties LIKE N'%dhaka%'
        OR (
            CONTAINS (
                judg.full_judgment
                ,'"*dhaka*"'
                )
            AND judg.full_judgment LIKE N'%dhaka%'
            )
        OR cd.name LIKE '%dhaka%'
        OR ct.name LIKE '%dhaka%'
        OR cjus.name LIKE '%dhaka%'
        OR judg.short_description LIKE N'%dhaka%'
        )
    AND judg.STATUS = 1
GROUP BY judg.id
    ,judg.jud_no
    ,judg.jud_year
    ,judg.book_reference
    ,judg.jurisdiction
    ,judg.case_no
    ,judg.case_source
    ,judg.parties
    ,judg.lawyer
    ,judg.judgment_date
    ,judg.j_date
    ,judg.judgment_date_type
    ,judg.short_description
    ,judg.section
    ,judg.act
    ,judg.article
    ,judg.order_rule
    ,judg.full_judgment
    ,judg.judgment_type
    ,judg.court_division_id
    ,judg.file_name
    ,judg.file_rename
    ,judg.judgment_entry_date
    ,judg.STATUS
    ,judg.user_id
    ,judg.is_pdf
    ,judg.is_table
    ,judg.is_correction
    ,ct.name
    ,cd.name
ORDER BY judg.jud_year DESC
    ,judg.jud_no DESC
    ,judg.judgment_date DESC OFFSET 0 ROWS

FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY
```

> Filename:
> C:\inetpub\vhosts\janatajobs.com\httpdocs\lcms_sys\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 331

Comment: Full-Text Search is an optional component of the SQL Server Database Engine. If you didn't select Full-Text Search when you installed SQL Server, run SQL Server Setup again to add it.

Answer (score 0):

Verify following:

1. `SQL Full-text filter Daemon Launcher` service running along with `SQL Service`, if not available, you may want install it
2. Once Full-text service started, verify `Full Text Catalogs` been configured in particular database (via *SSMS - Database - Storage - Full Text Catalogs*). [for detailed steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/create-and-manage-full-text-catalogs?view=sql-server-2017)